# Standard ML: how to compile a ML program using mosmlc?

Tags: sml

I would like to compile my ML program into a executable binary using mosmlc. However, I could not find much information on how to do it.

The code that I'd like to compile is here http://people.pwf.cam.ac.uk/bt288/tick6s.sml

cx,cy,s,imgLocation are 4 arguments that I'd like to take from command line arguments. For instance, if the program is compiled with name `mandelbrot`, input `bash$mandelbrot -0.5 0.15 0.0099 image.png` should execute the main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put this code into a file `foo.sml` and run

```
mosmlc -P full foo.sml
```

To get the command-line arguments you want function `CommandLine.arguments`, so, e.g.,

```
val (cx, cy, s, imgLocation) = 
  case CommandLine.arguments () 
    of [a, b, c, d] -> (a, b, c, d)
     | _ -> (usage(); Process.exit Process.failure)
```

You'll have to write your own `usage` function.

---

P.S. If you have access to `mosmlc`, you probably also have access to the interactive `mosml`, which has an incredibly useful `help` function with type `string -> unit`.

Comment: mosmlc doesn't quite work on the code: 

bash$ mosmlc -P full tick6s.sml
File "tick6s.sml", line 76, characters 13-15:
! val _ = main(cx:real,cy:real,s:real,imgLocation:string);<EOF>
!              ^^^^^^^
! Unbound value identifier: cx

Comment: it's working fine now. If anyone is interested, please click the link in my original question to see the revised code.